# How to remove duplicate data from child object called in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, eager-loading

```
            var eventDetails = (from e in db.tb_Event                            

                            select new
                            {
                                e.EventID,
                                e.tb_Customer.CustomerName,
                                e.StartDate,
                                e.EndDate,
                                loc = (from l in db.tb_EventLocation where l.EventID == e.EventID select new { l.tb_Location.LocationName }).Distinct(),
                                e.Objective

                            });
```

This is the correct way do do it. Try this out, this is working fine for me. Since you cannot use Include() for filtering you have to use projection technique.

Comment: how does your model looks like? and what do you mean by `I am getting it multiple times`..?

Comment: @BagusTesa- I got the answer. Earlier I was using Include() which do not allow filtering of data so I switched to projection method and got the desired result. My code- 
var eventDetails = (from e in db.tb_Event select new {e.EventID, 
e.tb_Customer.CustomerName,
 e.StartDate, e.EndDate,
 loc = (from l in db.tb_EventLocation 
where l.EventID == e.EventID select new { l.tb_Location.LocationName }).Distinct(), e.Objective
                                });

Comment: whoa! nice approach on figuring it, why don't you post it on the answer section?

Comment: @BagusTesa I have added it.

Comment: uh wait, i mean.. not editing your question but writes them in the answer section..